# If There Are Fairies That can Control the Elements (Earth, water, fire, air, and aether), If They Got Into A War, How would it be like?

Tags: magic, warfare, classical-elements

I'm writing a story about how there are fairies that can control the elements (Earth, water, fire, air, and space), and they got in a war, with Fire and Air and Earth on one side, and Water and Aether on the other, how would it be like? Earth fairies can build earth walls and control the plants. Fire fairies can only cover about one mile with fire, but the most powerful can cover a distance of five miles. Water fairies can only control a small amount of water, and the most powerful can create tiny tsunamis. Air fairies can control the air, and the normal fairy can control enough wind to know three to five other fairies over, and can create small air monsters, as can the other fairies except for aether fairies. The most proficient can knock down eight to ten other fairies with one gust of wind. Aether fairies create explosions and weapons like bows and arrows, the only weapon that the fairies use besides their magic, with the most powerful creating explosions as big as the atom bomb. There are also fairies of a mix, which are the most powerful, having the gifts and magic of all the fiaries, just combines, although they are neutral, even though each side wants them. How would the war be like? I'm not asking you to write a story, just describe how it would be like. Scary? Dangerous? Or possibly even exciting? Which side, in your opinion, would win? The fire-air-earth side? Or the water-aether side? Or perhaps the fairies of a mix will win, although being neutral. Again, I am not asking you to write the story for me. Thank you.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed for a number of reasons:  We are being asked to make up the story rather than the world the story exists in and there's nowhere near enough information to determine an answer.  What does "control the elements" mean?  One fairy with "fire" power can cover the world in fire or can ignite a bit of tinder that they are touching?  What does control of "Aether" mean at all?  Where do the mixed fairies sit in terms of "sides"?

Comment: Do you really think it is smart to circumvent the rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Air wins - they build a pressurized, underground hideout and vacum the atmosphere off the planet.

Alternatively, Earth might be able to split atoms.

This is pretty vague; you should edit your question to further elaborate on what they're capable of.